# lists similarity

Tags: function

if i have to list of concepts and i want to find the similarity between these list how can i find how much two list similar? as an example if i have two list that describe book attribute list1(author, brand , isbn, category, amount) list2(author , price , brand)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to calculate the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between each of the elements of the list.

Comment: yes i will use edit distance to caculate the similarity betwwen concept names but also i want to calculate the percent of similarity between two lists i saw this function 
similarity= n/m 
where n is the number of matched concepts and m is the smaller cardinality of two lists 
i dont know if it is correct i see that m must be the list with more number of concepts 
do you agree me??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jaccard index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) to compare the similarity of two sets.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl**

Use this module , for comparing two lists elements. 
Compare  # Compare elements of  two or more lists

> List::Compare ;

```
use  Data::Dumper ; 
use lib  "specify the path ";
use List::Compare;

@Llist= ( 1,2,3,4,6)  ;
@Rlist=(101,3,4,5,20,30) ;

$lc = List::Compare->new( \@Llist, \@Rlist);

print  Dumper \$lc->get_intersection();
```

Comment: I have given you the example perl code for your requirement. 
go through  and get to know.