# list comparision

Tags: compare

i want to calculate the percent of similarity between two lists as an example if i have two list that describe book attribute list1(author, brand , isbn, category, amount) list2(author , price , brand) 
i saw this function similarity= n/m where n is the number of matched concepts and m is the smaller cardinality of two lists i dont know if it is correct i see that m must be the list with more number of concepts do you agree me??

Comment: Yes, I would think that m represents the length of the list with more "concepts" as you call them.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392240/lists-similarity

Comment: yes it is a duplicate as you say but i need an answer

Answer (score 0):

The Python standard library has a class called `difflib.SequenceMatcher` that can compute this degree of similarity for any two lists.